# Forms Authentication redirects in WCF

Tags: wcf, forms, forms-authentication

When using forms authentication in asp.net how do I stop a 302 redirect to a web page when a WCF service is being accessed?

It is the desired behaviour when the client is accessing an aspx page requiring authentication, but a WCF service shouldn't be redirected to an HTML page when Authentication fails.

Any ideas?

Tom.

Comment: What do you want to happen when they access the WCF service and they haven't authenticated? is this a REST service being called from Javascript on a page where they should already have authenticated?

Comment: I want to send them a JSON formatted error.  It will be used to respond to AJAX requests.  If the authentication times out while the user is looking at the page, then the AJAX request will get a redirect to the login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

add a method in your login service as LogOn and return whatever you want when user is Unauthorized.

```
public String LogOn()
    {
        return "Unauthorized";
    }
```

then update web config as follows

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/LoginService.svc/LogOn"  />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour with Forms Authentication.

Generally one does not use forms authentication with WCF services, since the WCF client cannot respond to the login form.

The best way to fix this is to change the authentication method on the WCF service

**Edit**

Based on your comments, it could be one of two things:

- The AJAX request is being sent before the user logs in
- The authentication cookie is not being sent with the AJAX request

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So when using WCF for responding to AJAX requests from within the same .net site, it shouldn't be using the same authentication?